# How to constrain an object to one of it's local axes?

Tags: axis

How can I make it so that when I move it around, it will only move on it's local Y axis?

Comment: Use G to grab then Y twice (Y and Y) to have local Y axis displacement.

Answer (score 1):

You would use constraints. There are all kinds of constraints, tracking constraints, IQ constraints, spline constraints, camera constraints. I think you're looking for Limit Location, though. Check here:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/rigging/constraints/index.html

Comment: Yup.  If you add a limit location constraint and check all boxes except the ones which limit Y location, then change it from global space to local space, it will only move on it's local Y axis.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking for constraints as you mean as he says "**I** move it around".

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe not. I think someone else got it with local transform, xx, yy etc.